# How does ubuntu determine inactivity before suspending?

Tags: suspend

I have set it to "suspend when inactive" after 30 minutes.

How does it determine whether it is inactive? Is it just user input via keyboard/mouse?

If I leave a program working away - say processing a video, which takes a long time, will it suspend after 30 minutes and stop that program?  Same question for long downloads, will it suspend halfway through.

Comment: Have a search for `wake up calls`.

Comment: In Askubuntu?  I just tried it and all the answers seem to pertain to waking the system from suspend or similar.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Good question. Let's find out!

1. Beginning by [investigating](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/power/power.ui?id=a27cb5d26e789e76d01f44ab27f91e410dc9b03f#n106) the "Suspend when inactive for" option,

   ```xml
   <property ...>Suspend when inactive for</property> ...
   <object ... id="combobox_sleep_ac">
   ```

   we can learn that it [sets](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/power/cc-power-panel.c?id=a27cb5d26e789e76d01f44ab27f91e410dc9b03f#n1047) a GSettings key called `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`:

   ```c
   widget = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (..., "combobox_sleep_ac")); ...
   g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT(widget), "_gsettings_key", "sleep-inactive-ac-timeout");
   ```

   The [documentation](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/data/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.gschema.xml.in.in?id=410c71a0ab858d6c2ff3a67d707049e443880a06#n43) for this key provides a brief description:

   > The amount of time in seconds the computer on AC power needs to be inactive before it goes to sleep. A value of 0 means never.

   but still doesn't explain what "inactive" means.
2. [Searching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104782/how-can-i-search-the-ubuntu-source-code) for `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` leads us to [GNOME Settings Daemon](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/power/gsd-power-manager.c?id=410c71a0ab858d6c2ff3a67d707049e443880a06#n3257),

   ```c
   timeout_sleep = g_settings_get_int (..., "sleep-inactive-ac-timeout");
   ```

   which [periodically checks](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/power/gsd-power-manager.c?id=410c71a0ab858d6c2ff3a67d707049e443880a06#n3103) a property of GNOME Session called `Presence.status`:

   ```c
   result = g_dbus_proxy_get_cached_property (...->session_presence_proxy, "status");
   ```

   If it finds that the status is [idle](http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#id349443), it [puts the system to sleep](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/power/gsd-power-manager.c?id=410c71a0ab858d6c2ff3a67d707049e443880a06#n3179):

   ```c
   idle_set_mode (..., GSD_POWER_IDLE_MODE_SLEEP);
   ```

   So we need to learn how GNOME Session decides whether the system is "idle."
3. Following backwards from where GNOME Session [updates](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-session/tree/gnome-session/gsm-presence.c?id=e59b938c644a78236fd5ed9d708022be3b990ddc#n126) the value of `Presence.status`,

   ```c
   gsm_presence_set_status (presence, GSM_PRESENCE_STATUS_IDLE, ...);
   ```

   we can see that it [uses](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-session/tree/gnome-session/gs-idle-monitor.c?id=e59b938c644a78236fd5ed9d708022be3b990ddc#n272) the `IDLETIME` counter from Xorg:

   ```c
   if (... && strcmp (counters[i].name, "IDLETIME") == 0) {
       ...->counter = counters[i].counter;
   ```
4. The `IDLETIME` counter's behavior is summarized in a [blog post](http://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2009/08/17/gnome-power-manager-and-blanking-removal-of-bodges/) by the author of GNOME Power Manager:

   > gnome-power-manager uses a counter inside Xorg called IDLETIME. This counter is incremented only when the user does not move the mouse, or click some keys. When the user clicks something, the IDLECOUNTER is reset.

This tells us that Ubuntu determines inactivity by measuring the amount of time that has passed since the last keystroke or mouse motion. CPU usage and network activity do not factor in.

Comment: as you said in last line why The CPU usage not considerable ? My doubt is i came from http://askubuntu.com/questions/215870/how-can-i-shutdown-my-pc-when-the-system-is-idle . because if i put download of 1GB file then it can take a lot of time . even I am afk My PC still doing download of that file right . That means my PC active right ? :D

Comment: +1 for excellent investigation and breakdown. And @AgentCool, no. Activity is determined by keyboard or mouse press. Your download isn't going to press any keys and keep the PC awake.

Comment: @Oxwivi thats comment almost a year ago . not after the edit. :)

Comment: @AgentCool My bad, I didn't notice. The post was recently bumped, likely due to yesterday's edit. Was a question I was interested in, so checked it.

Comment: Awesome Socratic method!

Comment: Is answer this still true for current GNOME/Xorg versions? AFAIK, playing media also keeps the PC awake. Additionally some programs, like e.g. Matlab, keep the PC permanently awake, too.